# Zip a Grouped IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

```
public delegate void QuoteChangeEvent(IQuote q);

var priceChangedObservable = Observable.FromEvent<QuoteChangeEvent, IQuote> 
    (handler =>
    {
        QuoteChangeEvent qHandler = (e) =>
        {
            handler(e);
        };

        return qHandler;
    },
    qHandler => api.MAPI.OnQuoteChange += qHandler,
    qHandler => api.MAPI.OnQuoteChange -= qHandler);

    var grouped = priceChangedObservable
    .GroupBy(instrument => instrument.Symbol);
```

So `grouped` is of `type` `IObservable<IGroupedObservable<string, IQuote>>`

Two questions.

1) I tried to

```
grouped.SortBy(instrument => instrument.Symbol);
```

But `SortBy` does not seem to exist?

2)
   Say there are two symbols that come in, GOOG and AAPL into `grouped`.  How do I use the `Zip` operator so that what I get when I `Subscribe` is a `Tuple<IQuote, IQuote>` ?

I can't quite get the right syntax. Something like:

```
Observable.Zip(?, ?, (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b))
    .Subscribe(tup => Console.WriteLine("Quotes: {0} {1}", tup.item1, tup.item2));
```

**EDIT 1**

I almost got it:

```
    var first = grouped.Where(group => group.Key == "GOOG").FirstAsync();
    var second = grouped.Where(group => group.Key == "AAPL").FirstAsync();

    Observable.Zip(first, second, (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b))
    .Subscribe(tup => Console.WriteLine("Quotes: {0} {1}", tup.Item1, tup.Item2));
```

The problem is that `tup` is not of type `<IQuote, IQuote>`, but of type:

`Tuple<IGroupedObservable<string, IQuote>, IGroupedObservable<string, IQuote>>`

Comment: Seems like one of your operators is not doing what you think it’s doing. Overall, what is it you are trying to do? The problem description does not make sense to me.

Comment: I am creating an IObservable from an event. Since that event get can fire on any symbol, say GOOG and AAPL, I separate those out with the grouped. Now, from the grouped, I want to create a Tuple so that each event to the Subscribe consists of one object of type Tuple<IQuote, IQuote>.

Comment: Yeah, it’s that last part that I don’t get. A grouping consists of a key and an iterable set of values under that key.

Answer (score 0):

How does this look to you?

```
IObservable<(IQuote, IQuote)> results =
    grouped
        .Publish(gs =>
            gs
                .Where(g => g.Key == "GOOG")
                .SelectMany(g => g)
                .Zip(
                    gs
                        .Where(g => g.Key == "AAPL")
                        .SelectMany(g => g),
                    (x, y) => (x, y)));
```